# How to pass value from an activity in an broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-manifest

How to read data from an activity in an broadcast receiver if the broadcast receiver is registered through the manifest file??? Please Help...

Comment: [Please do some search before posting a question to any forum](http://tinyurl.com/5t69f4b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to store data in SharedPreferences and then get them into broadcast receiver.

You can use the code below in manifest file :

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in code you can use :

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            //updateWidget();
            SharedPreferences prfs = context.getSharedPreferences("defaul", 0);
            boolean bb=prfs.getBoolean("eer",false);
            alarm=context.getSharedPreferences("def", 0).getString("alarm_time","");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but could you please help me rectify my mistake in this code. I applied your advice and it seems to work but I am quite confused on this:

In my main activity I have code like this
public class CarMaintainerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public static SharedPreferences appData;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_AP = "DataAP";
}

I can successfully store my data on this APP_PREFERENCES_AP string.

Comment: In my broadcast receiver class:
public class JobService extends BroadcastReceive {
NotificationManager nm1;
String alarm;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {
SharedPreferences prfs = context.getSharedPreferences("default", 0);
         boolean bb=prfs.getBoolean("eer",false);
         alarm=context.getSharedPreferences("default", 0).getString(CarMaintainerActivity.APP_PREFERENCES_AP,"");

}

But this alarm string value appears to be null after the execution of the code...Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling broadcast receiver thru code then u can call it like as below

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, TimeAlarm.class)
intent1.putExtra("var1", "value");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
             intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: No, my code requires that the broadcast reciever starts automatically at boot. So I cannot call it through code. Is there any other way to do it if I want to call it throught the boot intent of manifest file?

Comment: Then first u need to store data in Preference files..then u can use <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

Not getting value from activity to receiver class which extends Broadcast Receiver

```
Intent inte = new Intent();
    inte.setAction("MyBroadcast");

    inte.putExtra("Phone_number1", phoo1);
    inte.putExtra("Phone_number2",phoo2);
    inte.putExtra("Phone_number3", phoo3);
    sendBroadcast(inte);
```

---

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

          String phoo1 = (String) extras.get("Phone_number1");//getting null value
          String phoo2 = (String) extras.get("Phone_number2");
          String phoo3 = (String) extras.get("Phone_number3");
          System.out.println("Value Of Contact Numbers Outside intent in Reciver");
          System.out.println("Value Of First Contact Number"+phoo1);
          System.out.println("Value Of Second Contact Number"+phoo2);
          System.out.println("Value Of Third Contact Number"+phoo3);
}
```